# Access of (as of yet) undefined Property AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, undefined

I have a function that creates a pointer on the screen after certain other conditions are met. I have a separate function that I use for moving the pointer around the screen (since the conditions for the first function and the second function are mutually exclusive). The problem, as far as I can tell, is that upon loading the movie flash instantly looks at all the code on the main timeline and realizes that my second function, the one for moving the pointer, is referencing the pointer's .x and .y even though the pointer doesn't exist. The second function's conditions prevent it from occurring until the first function has executed and the pointer has been created.

My question is, is there any command that I can use to tell flash "pointer.x and pointer.y don't exist YET, but by the time you need them they will, so chill" or do I need to start burying code on the movieclip itself or something? I'm still very new to AS3 so my methods aren't the most... Effective yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is some. You go into second function and check:

```
if (!pointer) return;
```

This will check if "pointer" exists, and is not null or undefined. Basically this is the correct method of programming, first check availability of your objects, then access them.